# Notification FCM android java doesnt work Service took too long to process intent: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE App may get closed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with firebase cloud messaging. I use the topic method to send a notification to android devices. It was working fine at the beginning, but after I tried several times, my android didn't receive any notification.
Here the response from logcat.

> Service took too long to process intent: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE App may get closed.
>   Service took too long to process intent: com.google.firebase.messaging.NEW_TOKEN App may get closed.
>   Background concurrent copying GC freed 253407(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 20MB/40MB, paused 99us total 119.008ms
>   Background concurrent copying GC freed 268107(18MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 22MB/44MB, paused 133us total 185.233ms
>   Background concurrent copying GC freed 302407(20MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 24MB/48MB, paused 1.088ms total 125.508ms
>   Background concurrent copying GC freed 328828(21MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 47% free, 26MB/50MB, paused 186us total 118.766ms
>   Background concurrent copying GC freed 318573(21MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 45% free, 28MB/52MB, paused 1.163ms total 120.955ms
>   Background concurrent copying GC freed 328906(21MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 43% free, 31MB/55MB,

and this is my notification:

```
{
    "to" : "/topics/new_articles",
    "data" : {
        "title" : "New Article: Menang atas perasaan hari esok updated!!", 
        "body" : "Artikel terbaru, baru saja di update, cek sekarang!",
        "topic": "/topics/new_article",
        "article_id" : "6"
    }
}
```

please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work that takes more than 10 seconds is blocked by the Android core
Foreground service should be used to fix the problem

this link can help

[Services overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Comment: Thank you, sir, I had a problem with pending intent at notification tap so my application load too long. Now it is working properly